# C++/WinRT WinUI3: How to get html source code by WebView2?

Tags: c++, winui-3, webview2, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk

I'm trying to use a webview2 control to get the body text of a website. But nothing showed.

My code:

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
        winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView2 web;
        std::wstring uriToLaunch{ L"http://www.bing.com" };
        Windows::Foundation::Uri uri{ uriToLaunch };
        web.Source(uri);
        co_await web.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
        winrt::hstring obj = co_await web.CoreWebView2().ExecuteScriptAsync(L"document.body.innerText");
        TextBlock().Text(obj);
        web.close();
    }
```

Thank you indeed for your advise in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to even compile, you should provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is in fact the code of testing, so could you please tell me how to do?

Comment: this is not a Minimal, Reproducible Example such as explained in the link.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++-winrt. in C#, it should be something like **await MyWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;")**

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your script. It should be like **ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML;")**